# Running the Double Tree Heuristic in a given graph - some slight confusion

Tags: graphs

I'm working on an exam question that asks me to run the Double-Tree Heuristic algorithm on the following graph:

[image]

This algorithm starts by finding a minimum cost spanning tree.

**My solution:**

Minimum spanning tree contains edges *ec, cb, dc, da*

Doubling these edges to find an Euler tour: a, d, c, b, c, e, c, d, a

Removing duplicate edges: a, d, c, b, e, a

**Actual solution:**

Minimum spanning tree contains edges ed, ec, cb, da

Doubling these edges to find the Euler tour: a d e c b c e d a

Removing duplicate edges: a d e c b a (cost: 51)

I want to know if I have used the algorithm correctly. Can there be more than 1 specific solution to this problem?

Comment: There can be more than one minimum spanning tree.

Comment: Just to clarify, there can be several solutions for this problem (including mine)?